# Matrix substraction differences in Python and Java

Tags: java, python, matrix

I have a problem with matrix substraction in Python and Java. I have followed the same steps in both programming languages but outputs are different.

```
import numpy as np
array1 = [[1,3], [5,6],[7,8]]
array1 = np.transpose(array1)

array2 = [[1,0,1]]
array3 = np.subtract(array2,array1)
print(array3)
```

which output is matrix like this:

```
[[ 0 -5 -6]
[-2 -6 -7]]
```

This works fine and in the way i need. But i need this output in Java. So i have tried following snippet of code:

```
double [][] array1 = new double[][]{
        {1,2},
        {3,4},
        {5,6}
    }; 

double [][] array2 = new double[][]{
        {1,0,1}
    };

array1 = np.T(array1);
double [][] vysl = np.subtract(array2, array1);
```

where

```
public static double[][] subtract(double[][] a, double[][] b) {
    int m = a.length;
    int n = a[0].length;
    double[][] c = new double[m][n];
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            c[i][j] = a[i][j] - b[i][j];
        }
    }
    return c;
}

 public static double[][] T(double[][] a) {
    int m = a.length;
    int n = a[0].length;
    double[][] b = new double[n][m];
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            b[j][i] = a[i][j];
        }
    }
    return b;
}
```

But the result is different matrix :

```
for (int i = 0; i < vysl.length; i++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < vysl[0].length; y++)
            System.out.print(vysl[i][y] + " ");
        System.out.println("");
    }

0.0 -3.0 -4.0
```

I have displayed the matrix with this 2D cycle. This matrix has only 1 row with 3 columns, but the preceding matrix from pythom had 2 rows a 3 columns. Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong a the way I can get the matrix with 2 rows and 3 columns in Java? How can I implement broadcasting rule in Java?

Comment: You don't implement the [broadcasting rules](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.16.1/reference/ufuncs.html#broadcasting) of Numpy in your method, which describes how to proceed when the matrices are not the same dimensions, which is normally required when doing matrix subtraction.

Comment: So, is there any method or a library in Java which I can use?

Answer (score -1):

I could see issue in your code...for your use case following code gives expected output

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[][] array1 = new double[][] { { 1, 3 }, { 5, 6 }, { 7, 8 } };

        double[][] array2 = new double[][] { { 1, 0, 1 } };

        array1 = np(array1);
        double[][] vysl = subtract(array2, array1);
        System.out.println("complete");
    }


    public static double[][] np(double[][] a) {
        int x = a.length;
        int y = a[0].length;

       double[][] c = new double[y][x];


        for (int i = 0; i < y; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < x; j++) {
               c[i][j] = a[j][i];

            }
        }

        return c;
    }

    public static double[][] subtract(double[][] a, double[][] b) {
        int m = b.length;
        int n = b[0].length;
        double[][] c = new double[m][n];
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                c[i][j] = a[0][j] - b[i][j];
            }
        }
        return c;
    }
```